# Стандартная страничка средствами flexbox

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Помогите пожалуйста разметить страничку стандартными header + content + footer

Вот моя попытка: https://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/wr70hscu/1/ . Она плоха тем, что для header, footer используется такое правило:

```
.icons_item:nth-child(6),
.icons_item:nth-child(1){
    width: 100%;
}
```

хотелось бы использовать чистый flexbox

Comment: А вариант добавить классы `header`, `footer` вместо `.icons_item:nth-child(6), .icons_item:nth-child(1)` и им уже прописать `width: 100%;` или    `flex-basis: 100%;`?

Comment: http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/qIAwr вот, кстати, отличный пример стандартной странички.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью flexbox можно разметить страницу так:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

section {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 3;
}


aside {
  background: grey;
  flex: 1;
}


header { 
  background: red;
}


content { 
  background: green;
}


footer { 
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>header</header>
  <content>
  <section>content</section>
    <aside>aside</aside>
  </content>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```